# Want button to add specific component contents to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope this does not sound complicated, but I have an array of objects that is mapped as a grid in one "page", as shown in one of the images below. Each component comes with a button that is nested in the component. I would like this button to change the 'selected' field of the component it is rendered with as 'true'. When this individual component is set to 'true', it is displayed in a separate 'page' under a list of exercises. I went in my exercises.js file and manually changed my selected fields to true to show what I would want, shown below. Both these pages use the same js file, since I am expecting the selected fields to change from false to true.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ggSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [1, "Needs a name"]
  },
  description: String,
  picture: String,
  musclegroup: String,
  reps: String,
  equipment: String,
  embedded: String,
  selected: Boolean
});

const Exercise = mongoose.model("Exercise", ggSchema);
const benchPress = new Exercise({
  name: "Bench Press",
  description: "Extend arms upward with barbell while lying on the bench.",
  picture:
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabianenavarro/Get-a-Grip/main/public/images/benchPress.png",
  musclegroup: "Upper",
  reps: "3x12",
  equipment: "Gym",
  embedded: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRVjAtPip0Y",
  selected: true
});
const barbellBackSquat = new Exercise({
  name: "Barbell Back Squat",
  description:
    "Perform barbell squats by standing with your feet shoulder-width apart. Take a deep breath and unrack a weighted barbell, holding it on your upper back. Keep your chest up and your back straight as you hinge your hips and knees to lower your body through a full range of motion into a squat position.",
  picture:
    " https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabianenavarro/Get-a-Grip/main/public/images/barbellBackSquat.png",
  musclegroup: "Lower",
  reps: "3x8",
  equipment: "Gym",
  embedded: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWl0apMgshk",
  selected: true
});

const defaults = [
  benchPress,
  barbellBackSquat
];


export default defaults;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import FilterGroup from "./FilterGroup";
import exercises from "../../exercises";

function onClick(){
  var objIndex = exercises.findIndex((obj => obj.selected == false));

  //Log object to Console.
  console.log("Before update: ", exercises[objIndex])

  //Update object's name property.
  exercises[objIndex].selected = true;

  //Log object to console again.
  console.log("After update: ", exercises[objIndex])
}

function ButtonNID(props) {
  return (
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button
          id="Add"
          type="submit"
          class=" btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary exercise-icon"
          onClick={onClick}>
          Add to Exercises
        </button>
      </div>
      <FilterGroup
        equipment={props.equipment}
        muscleGroup={props.muscleGroup}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonNID;
```

[image: My app with components shown]
[image: New page that shows exercises(manually changed on exercises.js, both shouldn't show]

So, the script I have is setting every component to true, which I get, however, I only want one of the components selected to true, and even then, they are still not being rendered in the Dashboard section despite the console showing me their selected values are "true". How can I fix this?

Comment: You're gonna have to use react state(`useState` for functional components) on this one, so that you can re-render your components and update information on the screen

Comment: my original thought, thanks for the clarification. Would this be in the file where my "list" is rendered?

Comment: It depends, you could implement this in a few different ways. The more simplistic way is to create an array of exercises and render them, the array of exercises is a state variable(`useState`). Changes made to the exercises array have to be triggered by the `useState` setter. The state updates will cause your component to re-render, thus rendering with the right information. If you find performance issues, give `React memo` a look, it could optimize the app.

Comment: Much thanks. I had an issue within the same project that was solved using useState. I will take this approach. However, would it still be possible for my button to only add one object from the array (set selected to true) instead of all of them?

Comment: Do you mean, to change the value of only one, or to do that without triggering a re-render of all the items? Coudn't understand if you managed to change the value from only one item but you're having unnecessary re-renders, or if you couldn't change items individually at all